# Criteria when $[ML:K]= [M:K] \cdot [L:K]$ holds

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $K$ be a field and $M,L$ algebraic field extensions and $ML$ the composition/product field.

I'm looking for some useful criteria when  the equation

$$[ML:K]= [M:K] \cdot [L:K]$$

holds.

Preferably more structural orienting on special cases of $M$ and $L$ and deeper then for example when $[M:K],[L:K]$ are coprime.

Comment: This site has many answers for this, start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988352/the-condition-that-lmk-lkmk-holds-in-the-field?rq=1) and follow the related links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly general result, not sure if it will be helpful.

Consider the canonical map $\phi : M\otimes_K L \to ML$ given by $m\otimes l \mapsto ml$. Observe that $\phi$ is surjective, and 
$$\dim_K M\otimes_K L = [M:K][L:K],$$
so $[ML:K]\le [M:K][L:K]$ with equality exactly when $\phi$ is an isomorphism (which is equivalent to $\phi$ being injective).

Note that if $M\otimes_K L$ is a field, then $\phi$ is injective, and conversely if $\phi$ is injective, then $M\otimes_K L\cong ML$ is a field.

Thus $[ML:K]=[M:K][L:K]$ exactly when $M\otimes_K L$ is a field.

This question, when is the tensor product of fields again a field, [has been asked before on MO,](https://mathoverflow.net/q/82083/69100) and has received some good answers.

Lastly, I should note Wikipedia has an article on [tensor products of fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_fields), and the property that $M\otimes_K L \to ML$ is injective is called [linear disjointness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_disjoint), and we say that $M$ and $L$ are linearly disjoint over $K$. See the link to the Wiki article for more on that.

Comment: Plus one, even though I found your answer more complete than OP needed, and probably beyond his current state of knowledge. I would have just appealed to the concept of linear disjointness, maybe with some examples of yes and no.

Comment: @Lubin I agree that it is hard to tell what the OP wants exactly from the question, since it's a bit vague and doesn't convey much of their own current understanding aside from some elementary field theory, but looking at the OP's common post tags on their profile, it appears they frequently post in AG/CA, so they should be familiar with the concepts in my answer. (Not that I'd checked before reading your comment, so any implicit criticism of my answer on those grounds remains valid)

Comment: A criterion like this is exactly one I was looking for. Thank you very much and sorry if the question contains some vague formulations. The background was to decide when the equation above holds for algebraic extensions on the shape $K(a), K(b)$ but this concept of linear disjointness provides of course an overkill for this case.

Comment: @KarlPeter Glad to hear that it was useful :)